# Adding few static Html pages to website: Good/Bad practices?

Tags: asp.net

I've this **old and static** website which is just a collection of html pages created in 2005 using DreamWeaver. I need to recreate it in ASP.NET MVC.

However, I've noticed that there few contents that are not susceptible to change over time, such as The Ministerial decree that created that organization, its mission, and a couple of similar things. So, I wonder if for those cases, I can just put the content on the page.

In one hand, that will speed up the development process. But, at the other hand, I fear that there be some principles I don't know yet that preach against using static pages in a modern website.

I've checked online to see if there are blogs/articles on that, but all I can find is "theorical stuff", such definitions, etc., but nothing precise on that mather.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Why not? Static pages are faster to serve as there is little processing involved on the server, the caching is simple on the client and they don't change.

Comment: *"against using static pages in a modern website."* <-- nothing against static websites. Dynamic is usually regarded as "best practice", but static website for static content is o.k. IMHO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no practice against using static content within a dynamic page/site (we all use static images, js and css after all).

If the content is not likely to change and is not duplicated, hard code it, use static HTML files etc...

I would even say this is good practice, as having static content means your application does not have to process it and the server will use less resources when serving it.

Comment: Thank to all. I fill better now. Anyway, you gave me good/bad practices I was looking for.